# Flutter: How to change values of switches created in loop?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, logic, side-effects

In essence, I have the switches created this way within an overridden `build`'s `State` method:

```
List<Switch> daySwitches = [];

for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

  daySwitches.add(Switch(
    (...)
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      days[i].active = value;
    },
    (...)
    value: days[i].active,
  ));
```

After that, the content of `daySwitches` is added in athe build method, this way:

```
 return Column(children: daySwitches);
```

The problem is that when I click on one `Switch`, any of them, there all changed altogether.  When I put a breakpoint in `onChanged`, I see that the variable `i` has the right value, but also see that all the `active` fields of each day are really changed altogether during the execution of this only line of code.

Why does this happen? Is it because I use a temporary variable (`daySwitches`)? Should I really use something like `return Column(children: days.forEach(...).toList();`, or so?

Comment: How did you initialize `days`?  Are the elements of `days` are all referring to the same object?

Comment: Can you provide full(sample) widget that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: @jamesdin. You're right! The array is indeed initialized this way: `days = List<TaskDay>.filled(7, TaskDay());`. Solved. Still a bit new with Dart/Flutter. Thanks.